# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined Ionic 3 /Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I got the below error on `Ionic 3` app.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///NewLoginPageModule/NewLoginPage.ngfactory.js:196:39)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14693:21)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13862:14)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14212:21)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14144:13)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13868:5)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14212:21)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14170:17)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13863:5)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14212:21)
```

*.ts*

```
    ulLoginForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

     ionViewDidLoad() {
       this.initForm();
     }

  initForm() {
    this.ulLoginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       password: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }
```

*.html*

```
 <form [formGroup]="ulLoginForm">                           
        <ion-list>
         <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password"  formControlName="password"></ion-input>
        <p *ngIf="ulLoginForm.get('password').hasError('required') && ulLoginForm.get('password').touched" class="error" padding-left>Password
        is empty</p>
         </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </form>
```

Comment: call ```this.initForm();``` in constructor.

Comment: It is not a good coding practice according to the Angular team. e.g. When we do a Unit testing and etc @fatemefazli

Comment: @Sampath can you explain this?

Comment: btw @Sampath where did you call `ionViewDidLoad()`??

Comment: It is a life cycle hook of `Ionic 3`: @SaurabhAgrawal https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: You could try `*ngIf="!!ulLoginForm && ulLoginForm.get('password').hasError(...) && ..."`.

Comment: Yes, That too work. But it has more work and not elegant too. @ConnorsFan

Comment: I hadn't noticed that the problem was solved. You may accept one of the answers to make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `Ionic 3` [**doc**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/), I was right about my implementation above.

***ionViewDidLoad   void***

> Runs when the page has loaded. This event only happens once per page
>   being created. If a page leaves but is cached, then this event will
>   not fire again on a subsequent viewing. The ionViewDidLoad event is
>   good place to put your setup code for the page.

But it is **wrong** when I implemented it. We need to use `Angular` lifecycle hook here like so:

```
export class NewLoginPage implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(){
     this.initForm();
   }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to give more info to the `Ionic 3` community about the issue of `ionViewDidLoad()` method. That is why I have posted it here. @UnluckyAj

Comment: fine from my side. but you can also edit my answer if you want to put more content

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that you want to access the formControl, but the initialization of the form is after the initialization of the component (because the `ionViewDidLoad` is executed after).

you could try to call the `initForm()` in the `ngOnInit` method, this is a lifecycle method of the angular framework:

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit{    
    ulLoginForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.initForm();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use angular life cycle hooks:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ztzzsu)

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }
  ulLoginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  initForm() {
    this.ulLoginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }
}
```